# how to move application from internal storage to phone storage or sd card

Tags: internal-storage

i am using HTC Desire SV and android version is 4.0.4. In it there are three types of storage- 1) internal storage 2) phone storage and 3) storage card. My internal storage is almost full and i am not able to do upgrade the apps or download new apps. I want to move few apps to other storage but not able to as it does not show the option to move to phone storage or sd card. Please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't move apps to SD card if the option is not available (as per the new rules of Google). You need to Root (**which voids warranty**) the device to be able to move apps from device memory to SD card and to remove default apps.